# Creating a Web Frontend using a REST API built for mobile application

Tags: php, rest, api-design

I have a REST API built with Slim framework. The API contains all the Models of the databases and has various endpoints that are accessed by my mobile apps. Now I want to build two different Web Frontend,

- A frontend that does the same things as the mobile app.
- A frontend that lets admins access and modify limited data on the database

For the first one, the API already supports everything I need. For the second one, I have to edit my current API app to support these new types of modifications and also have an API authentication method for admins.

My questions are,

1) Will going through API for the frontend be slower compared to direct access code

2) If I were to provide direct access to just the admins, I have two options,

- build a new app and reuse all the models. And this means including all my models manually in the new app.
- Edit the current API and have admin access controller return views instead of json (which I think is a bad practice)

I have checked some other answers on stack overflow, and although most recommend going through API, it is slower than executing directly.

My current thinking is to let the #1 frontend go through API as all the endpoints already exist. For the #2, as no API endpoints exist, and I will still have a build new controllers, I will just make a separate project that uses the same models as the API project, but this will mean having a web frontend being served directly from the API server itself.

**Edit:** I know I am kind of answering my own question, but what I want to know is the best design practice to do this.

Comment: *"what I want to know is the best design practice to do this"* - this isn't an appropriate question for SO, then.

Comment: The best design practice is the one that takes the least of your time, that does what you want and that doesn't use any hidden "magic" to achieve the desired outcome. You're asking for opinion, but you have to look at it from your own POV - what lets you be lazy and efficient?

Comment: @N.B. If I choose to go with a separate API instance, should I use PHP for the server side processing on the frontend or is there a better and faster alternative, as it will only be contacting the API server and will do no processing of its own.

Comment: If you already know PHP better than Node.js/Python - then yes, definitely do it.

Comment: As  long as you are adding API authentication for admins, add API authentication for all users - otherwise, I could in theory use your API and resources to do my own version of a similar app.

Comment: @ivanivan Yeah authentication for the rest type of users already exist. I am going to do add something similar for the admin.